# Passing JSON object to a webservice method

Tags: json, web-services

Does any one know how to pass json object in webservice methods. Here is how Iam implementing currently..

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/addSamples/{name1}/{age1}/{location1}/{name2}/{age2}/{location2}")
public String addSample(@PathParam("name1") string name1,
        @PathParam("age1") int age1,
        @PathParam("location1") string location1,
        @PathParam("name2") string name2,
        @PathParam("age2") int age2,
        @PathParam("location2") string location2) {

    SampleModel sfm = new SampleModel();
    sfm.setName1(name1);
    sfm.setAge1(age1);
    sfm.setLocation1(location1);

    SampleModel sfm2 = new SampleModel();
    sfm2.setName1(name2);
    sfm2.setAge1(age2);
    sfm2.setLocation1(location2);

    SampleModel model = sampleService.addSample(sfm);
    SampleModel model1 = sampleService.addSample(sfm2);

    return "true";
}
```

But I would like to pass name1, age1, location1, name2, age2 and location 2 as a single json object something like this..

```
[
    {
        "name1": "abc",
        "age1": "23",
        "location1": "XYZ"
    },
    {
        "name2": "def",
        "age2": "33",
        "location2": "MNO"
    }
]
```

Is there anyone who has tried this..If so please suggest me..
Thanks in advance
Regards
VHC

Comment: Instead of returning "true", return list of your object or array of your object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a array of such objects then pass this array to service.